# Jboss java process affinity settings

Tags: java, jboss, affinity

I have a requirement to bind JBoss and it's related processes (java.exe)  to 1 CPU of 2 Cores on a given server.

Problem is there are another java batch process running using there own separate java.exe so how to bind JBOSS invoked processes using affinity?

Please guide, i am on a windows server.

**Updated**: Or there is a way to identify java.exe using some identifier like if we add some parameter in JVM which can tell if present it is JBOSS initiated other wise others.

Comment: I found that we can use jps -v to find java.exe with it's Run time parameters to differentiate it.

Comment: I am trying to write a powershell which will fetch process Id using jps -v and then set affinity using powershell command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I am doing to identify Jboss initiated Java.exe, below is Powershell script. I hope you will find it useful.

```
$javaProc = .\jps.exe -v | select-string "jboss"
Write-host $javaProc.ToString().Substring(0,$javaProc.ToString().IndexOf(" "))
```